# antlr4 for parsing a method body

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, parse-tree

I am trying to parse a specific method body by employing the grammar provided here [Java Grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4). I tweaked the grammar a bit by modifying the starting parse rule (i.e compilationUnit) to also include the **classBodyDeclaration** as an alternative.

However, when trying to parse a method body such as the one shown below it fails to give me the parse tree.

```
public static String[] getCNs(X509Certificate cert) {

LinkedList<String> cnList = new LinkedList<String>();
String subjectPrincipal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().toString();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(subjectPrincipal, ",");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String tok = st.nextToken().trim();
    if (tok.length() > 3) {
        if (tok.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("CN=")) {
            cnList.add(tok.substring(3));
        }
    }
}

if(!cnList.isEmpty()) {
    String[] cns = new String[cnList.size()];
    cnList.toArray(cns);
    return cns;
} else {
    return null;
}}
```

I am using the parseMethodBody function shown below for parsing;

```
 private ParseTree parseMethodBody(String programString, TestErrorListener testErrListener) throws IOException{

        CharStream inputCharStream = new ANTLRInputStream(new StringReader(programString));
        TokenSource tokenSource = new JavaLexer(inputCharStream);
        TokenStream inputTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);
        JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(inputTokenStream);

        parser.addErrorListener(testErrListener);
        tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        return tree;

 }
```

I am able to parse some other method bodies. What comes as a surprise to me is that if I removed `LinkedList<String> cnList = new LinkedList<String>();` and the **if condition** at the bottom from the method above, the parsing goes successfully. Any hints what might be going wrong here? Is it a problem with the generated JavaLexer/JavaParser files, a lack of support in the grammar for some constructs (not sure about this since the grammar supports Java7).... Additional Info: The ANTLRErrorListener attached to the parser raises the **reportAttemptingFullContext()** as a false flag.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you passing a program with code outside of a method body and asking ANTLR to parse the inside of the method body?

Comment: I wanted to parse the inside of a java method body. I am using the grammar used for parsing a java file. I made a simple modification to the grammar by adding **classBodyDeclaration** as an alternative starting rule thinking  that the generated parser would be able parse full java class files and also java method bodies.

Answer (score 0):

> I tweaked the grammar a bit by modifying
>   the starting parse rule (i.e compilationUnit) to also include the
>   classBodyDeclaration as an alternative.

This breaks the basic logic of the grammar, which explains the oddness of when and if a parse-tree is generated.

The top-level rule that would match just the method given is, correctly, `classBodyDeclaration`.  Use that as your start rule (without otherwise modifying the grammar).

```
tree = parser.classBodyDeclaration();
```

Comment: the **typeDeclaration** parse rule wouldn't match the method declaration because the alternatives rules that it has( there should be a class, enum .... to match that rule). However, I am only interested in matching the method body and parsing the inside of the body. That is why I made the **classBodyDeclaration** one of the starting alternatives rules.

Comment: Looked like the method was wrapped in a block, but is just SO's formatting. Answer corrected. If this does not work, you may want to try the Java8 grammar - it is possibly more robust in handling generics.

Comment: yeah I did try with Java8 and making the classbodyDeclaration a starting parse rule, but still with no success :(  Does it still work if you attach an ANTLRErrorListener to your parser to make sure everything went smoothly ? Sometimes the parse Tree might be generated but it won't behave as expected if you don't have the ANTLRErrorListener attached to it.

Comment: Is it possible if you could post your tests and configuration of the parser you used for parsing the methodbody shown above?

Comment: Used your code for both. Is there a problem with your setup - mixed Antlr jar versions?